# untrusted_cert_title error when reinstalling MacOS Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal

I've wiped out my computer and am attempting to reinstall macOS as the final step of the process to trade in my Macbook Air; however, I get the "untrusted_cert_title" error and am unable to proceed. I've tried updating the date command per instructions I've found online, but continue to receive errors. Any tips? Thank you!

[image: Terminal command]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Are you following Apple support on how to erase a Mac from recovery boot and reinstall? If so, please edit that KB in your question. If you are following some other documented procedure - perhaps showing that will help us help you. It sounds like you did some research - be sure to show your research on the body of the question : - )

Comment: @bmike i found the issue below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't execute `MMDDHHMMYY`. You replace all those characters with the current date information.

If we were performing/entering this command in Terminal right now, since it is 16:14 for me on 05/01/18, we would enter the following command: `date 0105161418` and then hit "enter/return".

01 - 05/**01**/18

05 - **05**/01/18

16 - **16**:14

14 - 16:**14**

18 - 20**18**

Comment: I can't believe it didn't occur to me to plug in the actual values. That did it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jen no problem